# Iterate Sub properties of PowerShell Objects

Tags: arrays, powershell

```
PS C:\> $array

ReadWrite(AllHostsSpecified) : 
ReadOnly(AllHostsSpecified)  : 
ReadWrite(NegateSpecified)   : 
ReadWrite(Negate)            : 
SecFlavor                    : sys
ActualPathname               : 
ReadOnly(AllHosts)           : 
ReadOnly(Name)               : 
ReadWrite(Name)              : 
Anon                         : 
Root                         : {vin1,vin2,vin3,vin4...}
ReadOnly(NegateSpecified)    : 
ReadWrite(AllHosts)          : 
NosuidSpecified              : False
Nosuid                       : 
ReadOnly(Negate)             : 
Pathname                     : /vol/vin_binaries
```

Hi Guys, i have property root which is a dynamic property and which can vary from (vin1,vin2,vin3,vin4.......) which can also even get endless.

now when i do an export-csv i need to get output objects as below

```
ReadWrite(AllHostsSpecified) : 
ReadOnly(AllHostsSpecified)  : 
ReadWrite(NegateSpecified)   : 
ReadWrite(Negate)            : 
SecFlavor                    : sys
ActualPathname               : 
ReadOnly(AllHosts)           : 
ReadOnly(Name)               : 
ReadWrite(Name)              : 
Anon                         : 
Root (Property 1)                         : vin1
Root (Property 1)                         : vin2
Root (Property 1)                         : vin3
Root (Property 1)                         : vin4
.
.
.
.

Root (Property n)                         : vinn

ReadOnly(NegateSpecified)    : 
ReadWrite(AllHosts)          : 
NosuidSpecified              : False
Nosuid                       : 
ReadOnly(Negate)             : 
Pathname                     : /vol/vin_binaries
```

is there a way this can be accomplished?? like iterating within a for loop for all properties for Root???

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
filter ExpandProperties {
    $obj = $_
    $obj | gm -MemberType *property | % {
        #Find objects with array value
        if( @($obj.($_.Name)).Count -gt 1 ) {
            $count = 1
            $prop = $_.Name
            $obj.($prop) | % {
                #Foreach value in the property
                $obj | Add-Member NoteProperty -Name "$prop (Property $($count))" -Value $_
                $count++
            }
        }
    }
    #Output object
    $obj
}

$o1 = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    Name = @("Name1", "Name2")
    Root = @("vin1","vin2")
}
$o2 = New-Object psobject -Property @{
    Name = "Name2"
    Root = @("vin1","vin2","vin3")
}
$o = $o1, $o2

$o | ExpandProperties


Name              : {Name1, Name2}
Root              : {vin1, vin2}
Name (Property 1) : Name1
Name (Property 2) : Name2
Root (Property 1) : vin1
Root (Property 2) : vin2

Name              : Name2
Root              : {vin1, vin2, vin3}
Root (Property 1) : vin1
Root (Property 2) : vin2
Root (Property 3) : vin3
```

This also shows the original array property (ex. "Root"). If you want to exclude it, you need to use `select -exclude ...` inside the function. However, this creates a new "pscustomobject" (you lose the original objecttype), so I didn't include this in the solution above.

Comment: Hi Graimer, thanks for your reply, but i wanted to do it on the fly.. with the output of $array

Comment: You can't do it on the fly. PowerShell uses arrays to collect multiple objects/values. You need to create a "filter" to do the job. Mine is for your case, but itshouldn't be hard to convert the code to detect and expand all grouped properties.  I don't have powershell available atm to convert it myself.

Comment: Ignore the first lines, forgot to remove them. To make it expand every property with arrays you need to create a "filter" that uses "get-member" to get properties, then use ex. "Count" to get only props with array value, and then use my loop to expand all of them

Comment: can you share how to do that?